# How to update a component when navigator pops back to it?

Tags: react-native

My app uses Navigator for routing and screen transitions.

First screen has a list of items. When the user taps an item, it opens up a detail screen, where the user can edit it.

When the user is done editing and goes back (navigator's pop() function), the list doesn't reflect the changes done by the user. The screen has to be loaded again to to show the updated list.

Is there a way to forceUpdate a component in the Navigator's stack?

I tried the approach of using the 'onWillFocus' prop of Navigator, I can console.log the route, but don't know how to get a reference to the screen that is represented by the route and force it to update.

This correctly logs the route we are about to transition to:

```
_onWillFocus(route) {
         console.log('will transition to ' + route.name)
},
```

...

```
<Navigator 
          ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
          style={{flex:1}}
          configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          onWillFocus={this._onWillFocus}
/>
```

Comment: Isn't there a state change that should cause a `render` of the `ListView`? If there isn't one, re-rendering shouldn't have any effect and will render the old data, unless you're render is relying on object mutations, which is not the way to go with `react`.

Comment: Putting a console.log in the 'render' method of the list screen confirms that it is in fact being called when the user returns to the screen. I just realized I was doing something dumb:  the datasource was only defined once in getInitialState, but I didn't put code anywhere to update it. The only way for the data to update was when the whole component was reloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you really want to use the `onWillFocus` event because that makes the most sense in your case, here's one way to do it:

Modify your `renderScene` method so a reference to the rendered scene component is kept (while the component is mounted):

```js
renderScene(route, nav) {
  var Component = route.component;

  return (
    <Component 
      ref={component => { route.scene = component; }} 
      navigator={nav} 
      {...route.passProps} 
    />
  );
}
```

Then in your `onWillFocus` handler you can forward the event to your component:

```js
_onWillFocus(event) {
  const { data: { route } } = event;

  if (route.scene && route.scene.componentWillFocus) {
    route.scene.componentWillFocus(event);
  }
}
```

Finally in your component `componentWillFocus` handler you can do whatever you need to refresh the state and trigger a new render.

For other use cases, please have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

> For communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event. Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

Comment: I found your answer and I think it's exactly what I need. I'm a little lost at the `componentWillFocus` handle in the receiving component. How is this event implemented? Can you share an example? Can't figure out if it's a component event or Navigator's scene event. Thanks!